# Ionic 2: Map markers not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to display a map marker with no avail.

Constructor:

```
 constructor(navController, platform, app) {
    this.navController = navController;
    this.platform = platform;
    this.app = app;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.initializeMap();
    });
  }
```

Logic:

```
  initializeMap() {

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      console.log("Lat: ", resp.coords.latitude);
      console.log("Long: ", resp.coords.longitude);
    });

    let locationOptions = {timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

      (position) => {

        let options = {
          // /new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          setMyLocationEnabled: true
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

      },

      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }, locationOptions
    );

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.290270,103.851959);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      title: 'Hello World!',
    });
    var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    marker.setMap(map);

  }
```

Everything works fine just the map marker is not appearing.

I tried to create a new instance of the map and setting the other map's z-index to 1 but it's not appearing too.Even putting the whole marker function inside the inner function doesn't work too.

I'm guessing it might have to do with my "var map" is unable to locate map_canvas. How do I do it in this case?

**Update:**
Even after following Will's suggestion and trying with or without setInterval, the marker does not appear too.

```
  var myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
   function myFunction(){
     var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.290270,103.851959);

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatLng,
       title: 'Hello World!',
     });

     console.log("poof");
    marker.setMap(this.map);
   }
```

Update 2:
     In my css, I add the following lines of code which cause my markers not to appear.

```
div{
  max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

Removing it with Will's answer works.

Comment: Why do you initialise your map in the callback of the `getCurrentPosition` function? because this is asynchronous your map is being initialised after you create your marker

Comment: @Will.Harris Updated!

Comment: What I meant is you initialise your map inside the callback like this... `this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);`. But your marker code is not inside the callback so your marker code is setting it to the `map_canvas` but `map_canvas` hasn't been initialised at the point! Does this make sense?

Comment: You need to initialise your map before you call the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Google Map like this in Ionic 2 but this is where it looks like you are going wrong...

What you are doing is:

1. Getting the geolocation (asynchronously)
2. Creating the map and assigning it to `this.map` in the geolocation callback
3. Creating the marker and assigning it to `var map;`

The first problem with this is point 2 only happens when the asynchronous callback of point 1 is finished. At this point step 3 has already fired so you are technically adding the marker to nothing.

The second problem is you are setting the marker to a  different variable than what you set the map to so it wouldn't display the marker anyway.

What you need to do is:

1. Initialise the Google map
2. Make your asynchronous geolocation call
3. Set your geolocation callback result to center the map
4. Create your map marker and set it to `this.map`

This way regardless of whether step 3 runs before step 4 (because of the asynchronous geolocation call) your map is already initialised and the marker will appear.

So your code should look more like this (may not be completely correct but the order of doing things should be right)...

```
 initializeMap() {
   Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {});

   //initialise map
   let options = {
     zoom: 16,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     disableDefaultUI: true,
     setMyLocationEnabled: true
   }    
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

   //get geolocation and set center
   let locationOptions = { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true };       
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
     //setCenter should be a method to let you dynamically change the center of the map
     this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
   }, (error) => {}, locationOptions);

  //create marker and set to initialised map
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.290270, 103.851959);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: this.map, title: 'Hello World!'});
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! the marker is still not appearing even after this. I tried using setInterval function of 5 sec also doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I havent looked into this so not sure if it is a coding issue or a known problem with Ionic 2 and Google Maps. Could you try replicate your code in this http://plnkr.co/edit/L8JN6w5mqwbMY2E14dbk?p=preview and add it to your question so it's easier to see what might be wrong

Comment: I just had a quick look and it could be a coding issue. I will update my answer to show you the way of adding markers to a map as documented by Google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: Hi, my layout of my project is similar to this -> http://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/ . Even following his example doesn't work. Thank you so much for ur help!

Comment: I've tested this in my local project using Ionic 2 beta 6 and it does work. Is the marker you are setting at the same location of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`? because I get errors when i start trying to drag the map. So maybe if you are dragging the map to find the marker these errors stop the marker loading. Just a guess

Comment: Set your marker to the same position you use with `this.map.setCenter` to be sure the marker displays.

Comment: Alright i'll recreate a new project and try it out. Perhaps because i'm using ionic 2 beta 0.25